# Improve Performance with Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a Java program to solve this problem:

I have a balanced tree (namely, a TreeSet in Java) containing values. I have "Task" objects that will do either of the two things: try to find a value in the tree, or add a value to the tree. I will have a list of these "Task" objects (I used a LinkedList in Java) and I create threads to read and remove the tasks from this list one by one and perform their required action (i.e., find or add a value in the tree). I have created a synchronized "remove" method for my task list (which simply calls the underlying LinkedList's "remove" method). I have also defined the "add" method of the tree to be synchronized... (I don't know if it's necessary for it to be synchronized or not, but I assume it is).

How can I improve the performance of this program when using multiple threads? Right now, if I use a single thread, the time is better than when I use multiple threads.

This is the `run` method of my `TaskRunner` class, my threads are objects of this class and it implements `Runnable`, `tasks` is the list containing tasks and `tree` is my `TreeSet` passed to this object in the constructor:

```
Task task;
int action;     // '0' for search, '1' for add
int value;      // Value to be used for searching or adding

while (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
    try { task = tasks.remove(); }
    catch (NoSuchElementException ex) { break; }

    action = task.getAction();
    value = task.getValue();

    if (action == 0)
        boolean found = tree.contains(value);
    else
        tree.add(value);
}
```

Also, my tree inherits from `TreeSet<Integer>` in Java and I have defined its `add` method as `synchronized`:

```
public synchronized boolean add(Integer e) {
    return super.add(e);
}
```

And my task list inherits from `LinkedList<Task>` and its `remove` method:

```
public synchronized Task remove() {
    return super.remove();
}
```

Comment: How big is your test data? Are you testing into the hundreds of thousands of items?

Comment: Most likely most of the work is performed in synchronized blocks. Can you show us the actual code?

Comment: Using threads won't magically speed up your application. It's like saying that using more salt in all your meals will make them more tastier. You must understand what you're doing and how you're doing. Now, instead writing your question as an end user claiming for help on his unknown process, please provide the relevant code to replicate your scenario or a pseudocode showing your current algorithm.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I added some code to my question. Hope it helps...

Comment: I have created one example, but someone closed the question. thx.

Comment: No need to extend those classes and add `synchronized` to those methods. You have two options: use [`Collections#synchronizedXxx`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) instead or use a proper class that supports synchronization from [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package like [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) instead of `TreeMap`.

Comment: Actually, since this is an assignment, I'm now allowed to use classes in java.util.concurrent package!!

Comment: *since this is an assignment, I'm now allowed to use classes in java.util.concurrent package* We know nothing about your assignment, so we will suggest any option to enhance the solution. You have to specify the restrictions of your problem along with your problem...

Comment: The thing about assignments is they usually want you to do things you should never actually do in real life in order to get a point across. This is probably not the right site to ask this on since the users here are going to try to give you the best answer for real life situations.

Comment: Without wanting to do your assignment for you, you might want to think about what is going to happen if one thread adds a value to the tree while another thread is searching the tree.  You might want to read about the [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments; I'm not requesting that someone solves the assignment for me... I was just wondering if anybody can give me a clue on how I can improve the performance. That's why I didn't actually provide any code when creating the question. Because with this approach, I cannot think of any "parallel" tasks to help improve the performance. I was hoping to get some insight or some references I can refer to... maybe I need to change my approach, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

If your task class implements `Runnable` interface, you can use ThreadPool to process the tasks. 
Here is an example:

```
public class TreeSetTaskExample {

public static class Task implements Runnable {

    String      value;
    boolean     add;
    Set<String> synchronizedTreeSet;

    public Task(String value, boolean add, Set<String> synchronizedTreeSet) {
        this.value = value;
        this.add = add;
        this.synchronizedTreeSet = synchronizedTreeSet;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().toString();

        if (add) {
            System.out.println(threadName + "# add: " + value);
            synchronizedTreeSet.add(value);
        } else {
            boolean contains = synchronizedTreeSet.contains(value);

            System.out.println(threadName + "# treeSet.contains: " + value + " = " + contains + " removed...");

            if (contains) {
                synchronizedTreeSet.remove(value);
            }
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //
    // synchronizedSet
    //
    Set<String> treeSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new TreeSet<String>());

    //
    // ThreadPool with ? Threads
    //
    int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        String someValue = "" + (i % 5);
        boolean addOrCheck = Math.random() > 0.5;

        threadPool.execute(new Task(someValue, addOrCheck, treeSet));
    }

    //
    // don't forget to kill the threadpool
    //
    threadPool.shutdown();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much for your example. Although I am not allowed to use Java's thread pool mechanism in this particular assignment, it helped me learn about the thread pool...